# pandas calculate difference based on indicators grouped by a column with duplicated grouped pair

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Here is an example.

```
a b k c
0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0
0 2 0 0
0 3 0 0 
0 4 1 0
0 5 0 0
0 0 0 1
0 1 1 1
0 2 0 1
0 3 0 1 
0 4 1 1
0 5 0 1
1 0 0 0
1 1 1 0
1 2 0 0
1 3 1 0
1 4 0 0
1 0 0 1
1 1 1 1
1 2 0 1
1 3 1 1
1 4 0 1
```

Here, "a" is user id, "b" is time, 'c' is product and "k" is a binary indicator flag. For each c, "b" is consecutive for sure and binary flag 'k' of a unique pair (a,b) is same, which means it is independent with 'c'. What I want to get is this:

```
a b k c diff_b
0 0 0 0 nan
0 1 1 0 nan
0 2 0 0 1
0 3 0 0 2
0 4 1 0 3
0 5 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 nan
0 1 1 1 nan
0 2 0 1 1
0 3 0 1 2
0 4 1 1 3
0 5 0 1 1
1 0 0 0 nan
1 1 1 0 nan
1 2 0 0 1
1 3 1 0 2
1 4 0 0 1
1 0 0 1 nan
1 1 1 1 nan
1 2 0 1 1
1 3 1 1 2
1 4 0 1 1
```

So, diff_b is a time difference variable. It shows the duration between the current time point and the last time point with an action. If there is never an action before, it returns nan. This diff_b is grouped by a. For each user, this diff_b is calculated independently and for a same user but different product, it should be independent with product also.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to adding the c into the group indicator at second step

```
df['New']=df.b.loc[df.k==1]# get all value b when k equal to 1
df.New=df.groupby(['a','c']).New.apply(lambda x : x.ffill().shift()) # fillna by froward method , then we need shift.
df.b-df['New']
```